# Disconnecting a regular graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose graph $G$ which is a $3-$regular graph . Is it possible to disconnect $G$ with removal of only one edge ? I think it's impossible but I can't prove it .

Comment: Yes, there are finite cubic graphs with a bridge...I can't draw one here I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you send a reference or picture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cubic graph with a bridge:

[image]

Considering handshaking for the disconnected components, it's clear you need an odd number of nodes either side of the bridge. It's fairly easy to establish that those odd numbers must be at least $5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Is there a condition for the existence of bridge ?